# Javascript:disabled textfield when other field match certain word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I"m new in using javascript and trying to make registration form using java script/j query that when some user typing some word then the next input field will be automatically disabled. Example: User typing "Bread" in the field then next field go blank and can't be use.
I have try searching it on search engine but the answer only about disabling submit button.Below is my code:

```
    <script>
    function matchWord(e){
    console.log(document.getElementById('food').value.trim());
    if(document.getElementById('Food').value.trim() == "Bread"){
    document.getElementsById('OFood')disabled==true;
    document.getElementsById('PFood')disabled==true;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('food').onkeyup = matchWord;
    </script>
```

and this is my HTML:

Please Insert other food then bread

```
    Food:<input type = "text" name="food" id="food" value ="" size ="22" placeholder ="Enter your Favourite food"/><br>
    Drink:<input type = "text" name="Ofood" id="Ofood" value="" size="22" placeholder="Enter your Favourite Drink"/><br>`
    Restaurant:<input type = "text" name="Pfood" id="Pfood" value="" size="22" placeholder="name your best restaurant"/>
```

I also try to run the code,but it don't work. I need a solution.
That all thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element ID's are case sensitive. You also had some syntax errors. I've fixed your code for you:

```
<script>
    function matchWord(e){
        if(document.getElementById('food').value.trim() === "Bread"){
            document.getElementById('Ofood').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('Pfood').disabled = true;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('food').onkeyup = matchWord;
</script>
```

Tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/3pd40ep4/

Comment: Thanks,it work. but are there any other way to make it not case sensitive?

Comment: @Nexz, No it can't be case insensitive. Its designed this way to uniquely identify the elements.

Comment: @Samir Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of Typos in your script

```js
    function matchWord(e){
    console.log(document.getElementById('food').value.trim());
    if(document.getElementById('food').value.trim() == "Bread"){
    document.getElementById('Ofood').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('Pfood').disabled=true;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('food').onkeyup = matchWord;
```

```html
 Food:<input type = "text" name="food" id="food" value ="" size ="22" placeholder ="Enter your Favourite food"/><br>     Drink:<input type = "text" name="Ofood" id="Ofood" value="" size="22" placeholder="Enter your Favourite Drink"/><br>`     Restaurant:<input type = "text" name="Pfood" id="Pfood" value="" size="22" placeholder="name your best restaurant"/>
```

Comment: what if i want to use class name, can i use the same syntax as byId? I mean like this document.getElementByClassName("OFood").disabled = true;

Comment: Yes you can... but the thing is... Different elements can have same class name... but id is unique

Comment: if the id have another function,can we use it again for other function?